# Non-GNOME replacement for GNOME sound control

Tags: linux, audio, debian

I just upgraded to Debian 10, and can no longer run gnome-control-center from my WindowMaker session (errors out immediately, apparently due to now requiring GNOME infrastructure that isn't available). Is there a non-GNOME-dependent sound control app with equivalent functionality to the gnome-control-center panel?

I'm aware of pavucontrol but it's not a functional replacement due to how it refactors the controls. In particular, there's apparently no global control of the output device, just on a per-client level - which comes and goes depending on whether a particular app is running.

I'd try the KDE audio controls were it not that I can't even figure out what package they might be in, from the descriptions given.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually g-c-c which "refactors" the controls (setting the default as well as moving existing streams in one action). In reality those are entirely separate PA commands, and pavucontrol is much closer to PulseAudio's real settings.

To change the **default** output device (sink) for all streams, open "Output Devices" in pavucontrol and use the green "checkmark" button next to the device that you want.

The same can be achieved with `pactl set-default-sink` plus some scripting to move existing streams (sink-inputs).

---

The KDE equivalent (not counting pavucontrol-qt) is the `systemsettings` app, but I can't seem to find the audio section in the latest version. I do expect that it'll be very similar to pavucontrol though.

Comment: I am not seeing that behavior. If I click on the headphone device on the green checkmark, which has hovertext "set as fallback", it dims the button. But when I open up a browser tab playing audio, it starts on a different device that isn't checked - assuming that dimming == "checked" since it doesn't otherwise change the checkmark icon when clicked. I can go into the Playback tab and change the device for Chomium but I have to do it every time I start a new tab, which is the undesirable behavior. Is there anywhere else it's getting the default device from?